# Getting error when writing a query on createOrReplaceTempView in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

Below is my code in spark structured streaming with in foreachBatch

```
     df.writeStream.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {

     batchDF.persist

     batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("all_notifis");

      batchDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("api_notifications_topics");

       val meta_data= spark.sql("select topic,partition,max(msg_timestamp) as msg_ts ,max(off_set) as max_offset from all_notifis  group by topic,partition")

      meta_data.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("api_notifics_metadata");

      batchDF.unpersist()

     }).start().awaitTermination()
```

Even though I created tempview("all_notifis"), it is trying to fetch that table from hive default DB and throwing below error

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'all_notifis' not found in database 'default';

Can any one help on what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> LocalTempView means session-scoped local temporary views. Its lifetime
>   is the lifetime of the session that created it, i.e. it will be
>   automatically dropped when the session terminates. It's not tied to
>   any databases, i.e. we can't use `db1.view1` to reference a local
>   temporary view.

Can try if it can be accessing the table via `batchDF.all_notifis` or `db1.all_notifis`

if it does not works then  replace your view creation using

```
     batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("all_notifis");
```

and access the table using `global_temp.all_notifis`

Comment: that also I tired. But got "Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `global_temp`.`all_notifis`; line 1 pos 85;"

Comment: Yes.. I am trying to use with in the same session.. but getting the same error

Comment: @Raghu_Ram Were you able to solve this problem and how ?

Answer (score 0):

batchDF in your example has a different sparkSession.

```
batchDF.createOrReplaceTempView("all_notifis");
```

creates the temporary in batchDF's spark session.

```
spark.sql("select topic,...
```

will use 'spark' sparkSession and not batchDF's sparkSession.

The options available are, either use

```
batchDF.sparkSession.sql("select top...
```

or create the table in a specific database using "db.tablename" syntax